# Adding prices as checkboxes to Shopify collection filtering (without tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to add pricing filters as checkboxes to my collection filters. I need it so when you click on a price it will show you all the products with that price. I'm so close but it's not working. You can see it's current behaviour under "Price" with this link: https://creativeguild.myshopify.com/collections/cooktops/ pw: creativeguild

I'd also need it to be separate from the "Category" filter. Right now when you click a price, the selected price shows under "Category" which is not ideal. I'd need it to show under "Price" and not effect the "Category" selection.

It's also duplicated prices on top of not filtering by price.

If a Shopify dev could look at the code and correct it for me that would be amazing! Thank you

```
<div class="card__section card__section--tight">
    <p class="card__title--small heading">Price</p>

    <div class="collection__active-filters">
        {% for product in current_products %}
              <div class="collection__active-filter-item">
                  <button class="collection__active-filter-cross"
                          data-action="toggle-tag"
                          data-tag="{{ price }}-price"
                  >{% render 'icon', icon: 'close' %}
                  </button>
                  {{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros }}
              </div>
          {% endfor %}
          {%- if product.price != blank -%}
              <button class="collection__clear-filter button button--small button--transparent button--full"
                      data-action="clear-tags">{{ 'collection.filter.clear_all' | t }}</button>
          {%- endif -%}
    </div>


    <div class="collection__filter-group">
      <ul class="collection__filter-checkbox-list">
          {% for product in collection.products %}

                      <li class="collection__filter-checkbox">
                          <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
                              <input type="radio" class="checkbox" id="{{ product.price }}-price"
                                     name="{{ product.price }}-price" data-action="toggle-tag" data-tag="{{ product.price }}-price"
                                     
                                     {% if product.price contains price %}
                                     checked="checked"
                                     {% endif %}>

                              {% render 'icon', icon: 'check' %}
                          </div>
                          <label for="{{ product.price }}-price">{{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</label>
                      </li>
          {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the JS code, please post?